# Unique maximizer of product of monotonically increasing and decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I need to show that the function $g(x) = (x-c)(1-F(x))$ has a unique maximizer that can be obtained by solving $\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=0$. $F(x)$ is CDF of some random variable and $c$ is a positive constant. I am assuming that the support of $F(x)$, $[x^{\text{min}}, x^{\text{max}}]$, is such that $c < x^{\text{max}}$. It seems intuitive to me that since $(x-c)$ is a monotonically non-decreasing affine function and $(1-F(x))$ is a monotonically non-increasing function, the product should keep rising and then falling after hitting a certain level. But I do not know how to rigorously prove it. I wonder if you can provide any references or hints. I appreciate any insights.

Comment: What you want to prove is not true in general. Consider the instance with $c = 2$ and suppose $x$ is uniformly distributed with support $[-1,1]$. Then any $x \geq 1$ is a maximizer of $g$. At a minimum, you require $F(c) < 1$ for your result to have any chance of being true.

Comment: @madnessweasley Thanks for pointing this out. I just refined my problem statement accordingly.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the maximum might not be attained if the random variable has finite support. For instance, suppose the random variable has support $\{-1,1\}$ with probabilities $p(-1) = p(1) = 0.5$. Suppose $c = 0$. Then, the supremum of g on $\mathbb{R}$ is $0.5$, but it is not attained.